# MySQL UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now()) - current time in milliseconds

Tags: mysql

Is there a MySQL way to query based on current MySQL time in milliseconds?

I'm trying:

> SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) as now_in_mili

but both columns return the same (the 1970 epoch time).

I'm expecting 'now_in_mili' to print current date in milliseconds such as
it is possible in JavaScript:

> `Date.parse(new Date())`

Comment: Have a look at the documentation at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now, it's really well documented....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass an argument to the `NOW()` function to specify how many digits of fractional seconds you want it to include. It supports microseconds, but if you want milliseconds you can just use `NOW(3)` and then multiply the result by 1000, like this:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW(3))*1000 as now_in_mili
```

Comment: thanks I guess I was mistaken because both results started very much the same: :)
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW(3))*1000 as now_in_mili